# How to parse events in json format in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, fullcalendar

I have a script for full calendar listed below. Every thing is working fine. I returned events stored in database from controller in JSON format. Now that the format of json data is changed slightly, i could not parse to show events in calendar. Following is my script;

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: {
           url: "{{ route('event_calendar.data') }}"
        },

        eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
            var data = event.title;
            var start = event.start.format();
            var end = event.end.format();
            var csrf= "{{csrf_token()}}"
            $.post("{{ route('event_update') }}",{title: data, start: start, end: end, _token: csrf}, function (info) { $("#result").html(info); });
        },

        header: {
            center: 'month,thisWeek' // buttons for switching between views
        },

        views: {
            thisWeek: {
                type: 'agenda',
                duration: { week: 1 },
                buttonText: 'This week'
            }
        }

});
```

This is my previous data in JSON format which is acquired from url i.e `{{ route('event_calendar.data') }}`

```
[{
"id": 9,
"title": "Event 1",
"color": "#af2e0e",
"start": "2017-09-18",
"end": "2017-09-20"
 }, {
"id": 10,
"title": "Event 2",
"color": "#0b7c0d",
"start": "2017-09-04",
"end": "0000-00-00"
 }, {
"id": 11,
"title": "Event 3",
"color": "#378006",
"start": "2017-09-10",
"end": "2017-09-12"
 }, {
"id": 13,
"title": "Publication",
"color": "#378006",
"start": "2017-09-15",
"end": "2017-09-16"
 }, {
"id": 14,
"title": "other",
"color": "#378006",
"start": "2017-09-05",
"end": "2017-09-06"
 }, {
"id": 18,
"title": "other",
"color": "#378006",
"start": "2017-09-18",
"end": "2017-09-19"
 }, {
"id": 19,
"title": "Apple",
"color": "#378006",
"start": "2017-09-08",
"end": "2017-09-09"
 }, {
"id": 20,
"title": "Developer",
"color": "#378006",
"start": "0000-00-00",
"end": "0000-00-00"
 }, {
"id": 21,
"title": "New event",
"color": "#af2e0e",
"start": "2017-09-28",
"end": "2017-09-30"
 }, {
"id": 22,
"title": "asdasd",
"color": "#0b7c0d",
"start": "2017-08-28",
"end": "2017-08-31"
 }]
```

This is my new JSON data acquired from same url. Now as you can see there is a 'data' added at top events didn't show in the calendar. How to parse this form to show events in calendar?

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": 9,
    "title": "Event 1",
    "color": "#af2e0e",
    "start": "2017-09-18",
    "end": "2017-09-20"
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "title": "Event 2",
    "color": "#0b7c0d",
    "start": "2017-09-04",
    "end": "0000-00-00"
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "Event 3",
    "color": "#378006",
    "start": "2017-09-10",
    "end": "2017-09-12"
}, {
    "id": 13,
    "title": "Publication",
    "color": "#378006",
    "start": "2017-09-15",
    "end": "2017-09-16"
}, {
    "id": 14,
    "title": "other",
    "color": "#378006",
    "start": "2017-09-05",
    "end": "2017-09-06"
}, {
    "id": 18,
    "title": "other",
    "color": "#378006",
    "start": "2017-09-18",
    "end": "2017-09-19"
}, {
    "id": 19,
    "title": "Apple",
    "color": "#378006",
    "start": "2017-09-08",
    "end": "2017-09-09"
}, {
    "id": 20,
    "title": "Developer",
    "color": "#378006",
    "start": "0000-00-00",
    "end": "0000-00-00"
}, {
    "id": 21,
    "title": "New event",
    "color": "#af2e0e",
    "start": "2017-09-28",
    "end": "2017-09-30"
}, {
    "id": 22,
    "title": "asdasd",
    "color": "#0b7c0d",
    "start": "2017-08-28",
    "end": "2017-08-31"
}]
}
```

Comment: check what is the value return for `info` in previous working data using `console.log`, you might need to write `info.data` in order to get the same for the new set of data

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just copied all my script there. Please ignore code below `eventDrop` . The problem is that new set of data didn't parse in event calendar  from this method `events: {
       url: "{{ route('event_calendar.data') }}"
    },`

Comment: able to create sample jsfiddle for easy troubleshoot?

Comment: can't you just change your php function so it returns it without `data`?

Comment: it's no surprise it doesn't work because fullCalendar doesn't support that format. It supports the array format that you had originally. Why did you change it? There's no material difference except for some reason you wrapped it in an object. Seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably a better option to have your source return properly formatted data, but if for some reason you can't do that, you can do it in Javascript.

[The Fullcalendar docs describe](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) that you can pass normal `$.ajax` options in your events source.  So you can specify a success callback which returns the data in the format you need.

I tried this with your data locally and it works:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // ... your code
    events: {
        url: "{{ route('event_calendar.data') }}",
        success: function(response) { 
            // Instead of returning the raw response, return only the data 
            // element Fullcalendar wants
            return response.data; 
        }
    },
    // ... rest of your Fullcalendar code
```